# C# how to make ProcessCmdKey as public method

Tags: c#, methods, calculator

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.NumPad0:
                TheAddingResult(0);
                return true;

            default:
                return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
    }
```

i'm making a calculator and i wanna assign every button to certain hotkey but i can't do it i have to use this way which is not that much useful is there is a way that i can use this method like if it's any public method ? like in button_click event keydata = keys.numpad0 or type for example processcmdkey(keys.numpad0) is that possible ?

edit : 
someone wrote this code and then deleted it i liked it but i just want to know what to type in the first argument when summoning it

```
     public bool hotkeys(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        return ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
     private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hotkeys(ref  ,Keys.Back);
        erasingall();
    }
```

what should i type in the first argument when summoning ?

Comment: Why exactly is this method not useful for you? It helped me a lot in a similar case.

Comment: the problem is i have like the "+" button in the calculator which does some stuff if there is any simple way to like summon the processcmdkey inside the button so it can be easier rather than copying the whole code again from the original to the hotkeys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click directly in your button use ClickEvent and inside the subscriber execute your method with the appropriate parameters. Probably you will have to inject as dependency the class holding he method, or make the method static static, or create it directly in the partial class. For Example, something like:

```
 private void ButtonPlusClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.operationsContainer.Execute(Constants.PlusSign);
    }
```

where operationsContainer is the class that holds the method for operations.

If you want to enter input also directly from your keyboard, you can make KeyPreview True from the properties of your form and then use event for keypress like FormDetectKeyPress. For Example:

```
private void FormDetectKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        var pressedKeyValue = e.KeyChar;
        switch (pressedKeyValue)
        {
            case '+':
                {
                    this.ButtonPlusClick(sender, null);
                }

                break;
           default:
                return;

          }
```

You can add any operation with button click event in similar way and corresponding button from keyboard in the FormDetectKeyPress subscriber.